# Having issue in setting color for ion-label in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I was trying to color ion-label (floating element) in ionic 4 but needed to use !important in the property

```
<ion-row class="ion-margin-vertical ion-padding-horizontal">
  <ion-col size="12" class="ion-margin-bottom">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Contact Number</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" value="333"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
<ion-row>
```

I tried using custom style in global.scss

```
ion-label {
  --color: var(--ion-color-step-400) !important;
}
```

unable to do the same without important but was not working, but when I used !important it works.
Is it the correct approach? Need help.

Answer (score 0):

use `color="secondary"` in `ion-label` like below

using `!important` its also correct way, its override the default color or properties

```
<ion-row class="ion-margin-vertical ion-padding-horizontal">
  <ion-col size="12" class="ion-margin-bottom">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="secondary" position="floating">Contact Number</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="number" value="333"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
<ion-row>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct in the way, I can always use color property as input attribute but my objective is to add another custom color over and through out the application for ion-label. According to documentation I can use --color property in css but my question is why then I need to use ! important with it. So do I need to write the style in different file? What is the standard?

Comment: write style same page scss or global.scss and i given answer already using !important is override the property

Answer (score 0):

Its getting refereed from variables.scss file, which have full sets of :root css elements like primary, secondary, tertiary, success, warning, danger, dark, medium, light with their color codes as below.

So you can directly use these names to apply color which internally apply below properties, you can add further styling as per you needs.

```
  --ion-color-primary: #3880ff;
  --ion-color-primary-rgb: 56, 128, 255;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
  --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --ion-color-primary-shade: #3171e0;
  --ion-color-primary-tint: #4c8dff;
```

you should be able to use above mentioned default color properties without any additional ! important flag.

but if you want to apply any further additional override style, one needs to use important as per css standard as below.

The !important property in CSS is used to provide more weight (importance) than normal property [in this case default ionic class]. In CSS, the !important means that “this is important”, ignore all the subsequent rules, and apply !important rule

Comment: Yes I can use the color name as mentioned like (--ion-color-primary-tint), but if you can see my question, I am having problem when I am not using that without ! important. My question is can I use it anyway without using ! important.

Comment: Yes, Ideally you should be able to use above mentioned default color properties without any additional ! important flag, but if any further additional override property one needs to use important as per css standard as below.

The !important property in CSS is used to provide more weight (importance) than normal property [in this case default ionic class]. In CSS, the !important means that “this is important”, ignore all the subsequent rules, and apply !important rule

Comment: Yes that I understand. But my actual question is why not able to use it without *! important*. As per ionic documentation one could use directly. So my concern is am I missing anything or I am placing the css in correct file. Just wanted to know the standard. It will work fine with important as it will override everything but why can't I use it without *! important* like other ionic components?

Comment: Please share your variable.scss file and see if it contains Ionic CSS Variables or not, with :root selector, take reference of this link : https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-variables